# How to send sms from a VB application via USB GSM modem (Huawei E1731)

Tags: vb6, sms, usb, gsm, modem

I am creating a small VB project and I want to send some information through SMS. I tried to find solutions in here many threads but can get one.

I am using Huawei E1731 3G USB modem, which is capable of sending and receiving sms through its official software. How can i use the modem to send a fixed message to particular number by getting the number from text box in a form?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are using VB.NET and not VB6.

Here is a solution in C#.NET which you should easily be able to convert to VB.NET :
http://sharp-coders.blogspot.in/2011/12/send-sms-using-at-commands-via-gms.html

Comment: I am looking to implement this in Visual Basic 6.0 application. Here in forum, I am not able to change tags in my question. It automatically takes vb.net instead of just VB :(

Comment: Have a look at this for VB6 - http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?396032-Send-receive-SMS-through-GSM-Modem-using-visual-basic-6.0